# How to ensure population growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following problem :
Annual plants produce seeds in late summer, which is usually the end of their growing season.
increase. They then wither and die, leaving their progeny in the latent form of
seeds, a total of γ for each parent. A fraction σ of these seeds will survive
winter and, with probability α, germinate at the beginning of the following spring to give rise to
a new generation. The fraction that does not germinate remains dormant for another year, and if it survives
next winter (again with probability σ) then either germinates, with probability β, or
definitely die. Find the second-order linear equation associated with the total pn of plants
that germinate every year. How big must the γ production of seeds per plant be in
function of the rest of parameters to ensure population growth?

For the first question I have proposed the equation in second order differences:

$ P_{n+2} = \alpha*\sigma*\gamma*P_{n+1} + \beta*\gamma*\sigma^2*(1-\alpha)*P_{n} $

How can I solve the last question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution to the equation

$$P_{n+2} + C\,P_{n+1} + D\, P_{n} = 0$$

has solution $P_{n} = A\lambda_{-}^n + B \lambda_{+}^n$ (provided $C^2 \ne 4D$) where $A,B$ are  arbitrary constants and $\lambda_{\pm}$ solve the so-called *characteristic equation*

$$\lambda^2 + C\lambda + D = 0$$

Your equation describes population growth when the solution $P_n$ does not decay as $n \to \infty$. In other words, when at least one of $\lambda_+$, $\lambda_-$ is bigger than 1.

Well,

$$\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{-C \pm \sqrt{C^2-4D}}{2}$$

So clearly it should be enough to have $\lambda_{+} > 1$. In other words,

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{C^2-4D} &> 1+C \\
C^2-4D &> 1 + 2C + C^2\\
1+2C+4D &< 0
\end{align*}

This should give a solution for $\gamma$ in terms of $\sigma, \alpha, \beta$.